# F# convert json to csv: how to treat Option<string> as empty string?

Tags: json, csv, f#

I'm new to F# and I would like to use the JsonProvider to convert a simple Json file to CSV format. Here's my F# script:

```
#r "./lib/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Persons = JsonProvider<""" {
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "User1",
      "company": "",
      "address": "Streed, City"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "User2",
      "company": "",
      "address": ""
    }
  ]
} """>
let persons = Persons.GetSample()

for p in persons.Persons do
  printfn "%i;%s" p.Id p.Name
//  printfn "%i;%s;%s;%s" p.Id p.Name p.Company p.Address
```

If I uncomment the last line of code (**printfn "%i;%s;%s;%s" p.Id p.Name p.Company p.Address**) I get the following compiler error:

> This expression was expected to have type 'string' but here was type   Option`<string>`

What I want to achieve are the following 2 CSV like formatted lines:

```
1;User1;;Street, City
2;User2;;
```

How do I convert a Option in an empty string?

Comment: This is a duplicate. I recommend reading "The Option type" and "Match expressions" on fsharpforfunandprofit.com or documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching as mentioned by Tomasz in the comments.

Another option is to use the `defaultArg` function, which takes an `option<'T>` and a default value of type `'T` that is used when the option represents a missing value. Something like:

```
for p in persons.Persons do
  printfn "%i;%s;%s;%s" p.Id p.Name (defaultArg p.Company "") (defaultArg p.Address "")
```

Comment: Thank's Tomas, I find that the `defaultArg` suits better my needs because I do not have to pattern match all the possible fields that can be empty in the Json file.

Comment: After using the `defaultArg` for **Company** and **Address**, I get a new problem with the company field. Because none of the company elements in Json has a value, the compiler complains and says that the type is `IJsonDocument` and not `string option` as assumed by printfn (me). How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, in that case, the best option is probably to modify your sample, so that it contains one element with a valid value.